# Do Electrons revolve with super-light speed?

Tags: visible-light, electrons, faster-than-light, wavelength

Faster the particle, smaller wavelength. In the electron microscope, we use electrons because of its smaller wavelength?

Does it mean electrons travel faster than light?

Or simply measuring its speed beyond our understanding of physics?
(Heisenberg maybe fascinated by some future grandson.)

Comment: First, super-luminal behavior of massive particles is considered off-topic by most members of this site.  Second, the behavior of electron microscopes and why electron reflection/transmission is used rather than optical light is widely documented elsewhere.

Comment: Are you suggesting blue light travels faster than red light?

Answer (score 2):

You have the relation wrong. It's not faster the particle smaller the wavelength, but the higher the momentum of the particle the smaller the wavelength: $\lambda=h/p$. Electrons can not travel faster than the speed of light, nothing can. Even though an electron can never travel faster (or even at) the speed of light, the momentum can increase without bound as long as you keep pumping energy in it. This is because the relation between momentum and velocity is not a linear one: $p=\gamma m v$. Here $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ which clearly increases without bound as $v\rightarrow c$ but is undefined for $v=c$.  Thus, electrons can have much higher momentum than visible light and thereby have much smaller smaller wavelengths - which is indeed why we use electron microscopes.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Physics does not account for spin in terms of the rotation of an electron.

Q2. Yes electrons are used because of this.

Q3. No it does not mean this. It means electrons have larger momentum, as $\lambda=h/p$.

Q4. Measurement of the speed of an electron is standard physics.